# Finding the number of elements between i and j in an integer array in o(1)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Given an unsorted integer array and 2 numbers i and j such that 0 <= i <= j <= C(a constant say MAX_INTEGER) what kind of pre-processing can be performed on it so that you will be able to find the number of numbers between i and j(both inclusive) in o(1) time. The array can also have duplicates.

I had thought of building a frequency array f[] for the elements in the array(space o(C)) and also
another array cf[] for cumulative frequency(space o(C)).

So given i and j, i can look up the cumulative frequency array and do cf[j] - cf[i] - This will give the number of elements between i and j. To include i and j, look up the frequency array and add the values. ie cf[j] - cf[i] + f[i]+f[j]
Time complexity will be o(1) * 4 = constant time.

The look up in the frequency array can be avoided by finding the previous non zero cf array element for both i and j in the respective direction. This will increase the time complexity but will reduce the space complexity.

Wanted to know if there is a better solution for this problem.

Note - Values of i and j will be available to you only after the pre-processing is completed.

-Vijay

Comment: A [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) in one dimension is a binary search tree, giving you O(n) space and O(log n) lookup. Don't know if it's possible to beat O(log n) for this without using O(C) space.

Comment: Please note that "o(f(x))" is not the same as "O(f(x))". If some function y(x) is o(f(x)) it means roughly that as x gets large, y(x) will eventually become insignificantly tiny in proportion to f(x). So while there are many functions that are O(1), the only function that is o(1) is y(x) = 0 :-P

Comment: Provided there's no need to be able to efficient insert or remove elements from the array, your current solution is almost perfect. All I would suggest is that you can get rid of f[] altogether and just use `cf[j] - cf[i-1]` to calculate the answer.

Comment: If you don't require an exact solution, and have lot of time for pre-computing you could use machine learning. First create the matrix of all possible (i,j). Then use a genetics algorithms to learn a polynome of 2 free variables and degree related to the entropy of the matrix. Final space and time depend of the precision, and length of the polynome.

Comment: note that if you bound the limits of the interval you're checking beforehand (in your case by `0`, `C`), you'll have `O(1)` lookup time simply by precomputing the cumulative frequency array `c` for all ordered pairs of integers in `[0, C]^2`. The `O(.)`-notation is not entirely meaningful in this setting.

Comment: @mr-k: I don't think one can treat machine learning algorithms as black boxes in this case. Actually, I can not think about any machine learning algorithms that infer the answer in O(1) time in this problem.

Comment: We don't infer the answer in O(1), but learn for long very time a formula that give an approximation of the solution. The formula should be fixe length size.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine how you'd do this in O(1) without using O(C) additional space.

You can do the lookup in O(log n) very easily if you just create a sorted copy of the array on startup. (O(n log n)).

The lookup then becomes:

```
Binary search to find the first occurrence of i
Binary search to find the last occurrence of j
result = position_of_j - position_of_i + 1
```

Now, if the range of items in the array is relatively small, you could do it in O(max - min + 1) extra space and get O(1) lookup. But worst case, `(max - min + 1) == C`.

Comment: how could you find the solution in O(1) using O(C) additional space? I would be very grateful for any details you could provide on this query!

Comment: @duhaime Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I've corrected that first paragraph.

Comment: thank you for the update and for your question on Karthikeyan's proposal below!

Comment: @duhaime Actually, I'm going to revert my edit. The OP is asking how to pre-process the data so that he could do an O(1) lookup. So my O(1) comment about the lookup is correct. The OP explains how that's done.

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

First off, sort the integer array. and create a hash table with a key for every unique integer in the array and the value as indices in the array at which that integer occurs first and last in the sorted array,(since dup is possible). Space complexity of hash table would be O(n) and access complexity is constant, you have to allocate the space for hash table accordingly.

Given these extra data structures, if you want to find out the range of numbers between i and j, get first index of i and get last index of j, from the hash table and subtract the first from the latter to get the result.

Comment: What if i and j aren't in the hash table?

Comment: Yep, that would render this solution unusable. But without hash tables, I couldn't think of a O(1) solution. Whatever way I think of, I end up with at least O(log n) solution :(

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim result() as integer
Dim C(1000) as integer
Dim Buff() as integer
Dim i as integer=50 
dim j as integer=450 
for count =0 to c.count-1
    if c(count)>i and c(count)<j then 
       dim length as integer=buff.count-1
       redim result(lenght+1)
       for buffcount=0 to buff.count
           result(buffcount)=buff(buffcount)
       next  
       result(result.count-1)=c(count)
       redim buff(result.lenght-1)
       buff=result
    end if 
next
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is pretty bad in several different ways. (1) You did not test it, because sometimes you wrote `length` and sometimes `lenght`; (2) It will take O(n^2) time *per query* due to the loop-within-a-loop, while the OP's solution will take only O(1) time per query after a one-off O(n) preprocessing; (3) You grow arrays inside the loop, also forcing O(n^2) time.

Comment: How do you use yours arrays to implements a "function f(i,j) -> number of numbers between i & j" ?

Comment: I'm pretty bad at writing in English but i think it enters the second loop only when c(count) is greater than [i] and less than [j]

Answer (score -1):

Idea:

```
 1. Binary search to find the first occurrence of i               
 2. Binary search to find the last occurrence of j       
 3. result = position_of_j - position_of_i + 1
```

or

```
1. first enter size of array    
2. then enter elements of array    
3. then query size    
4. then enter left, right
```

code link : [HackerEarth](https://code.hackerearth.com/dc710bM)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. I would recommend including your code in a formatted code block within your answer.